# How to identify which website on my instance is receiving lots of traffic?

Tags: ubuntu, ubuntu-12.04, ddos

I am new to server administration and have just setup a new quad core instance which hosts around 15 websites.

Over the past couple of days my server load has been averaging at around 15.00. I believe it is because of one (or maybe more) websites are getting spammed by spambots.

Typing 'top' at the command line shows many processes from user 'www-data' which indicates lots of web traffic. Is there an easy way identify which one of my sites is taking a hammering?

Reading the apache error logs is a very difficult tasks as most of the websites receive daily traffic of 10,000 + unique users.

Any help would be appreciated!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I installed iftop and found it quite useful to identify which hosts were sending my server requests. However, apachetop was a better tool to see which files were being requested on individual vhosts. It also tells me which ip address's are making the requests

Answer (score 3):

Every vhost (domain) should write his own access.log

Then just compare the filesizes from the logfiles. For a more detailed statistic you should use a logfile analyzer like awstats ( http://awstats.sourceforge.net/ )

Comment: Theoretically, the most visited site may be not generating huge traffic. However, for example, in the `nginx` access logs there is a `body_bytes_sent` value. One may count it for every single virtual host and then compare the sums.

Answer (score 1):

You can enable the server-status module on apache. It's very good for seeing what's going on real time with your server.

(Make sure you restrict the access to the server-status module via .htaccess, don't make it public!)

Answer (score 1):

Install and use the software command line utility called **iftop** or use can also use the tool **wireshark** for better analysis.

Comment: I installed iftop and found it quite useful to identify which hosts were sending my server requests. However, apachetop was a better tool to see which files were being requested on individual vhosts. It also tells me which ip address's are making the requests